# subscribeOn not working when using it on ServerRequest's bodyToMono

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I know subscribeOn used to switch executing thread when sequence being subscribe, but I found it's not working with ServerRequest.bodyToMono/Flux

Something like

```java
Flux.just(1,2,3)
          .doOnNext(integer -> log.info("test {}",integer))
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
          .subscribe();
```

will make execution thread change

```
INFO 23313 --- [      elastic-2] c.a.p.m.f.service.router.TestService     : test 1
INFO 23313 --- [      elastic-2] c.a.p.m.f.service.router.TestService     : test 2
INFO 23313 --- [      elastic-2] c.a.p.m.f.service.router.TestService     : test 3
```

But what confused me is

Say I have a Spring WebFlux Router:

```java
@Configuration
public class TestRouter {
    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> testRouterFunction(TestService testService) {
        return route().path("/test", builder -> builder.nest(accept(MediaType.ALL),
          route -> route.PUT("/", req -> {
              Mono<String> valueMono = req.bodyToMono(String.class);
              return ServerResponse.ok().body(testService.test(valueMono), String.class);
          }))).build();
    }
}
```

and a Service:

```java
@Service
@Slf4j
public class TestService {
    public Mono<String> test(Mono<String> mono) {
        return mono
          .doOnSubscribe(subscription -> log.info("on subscribe"))
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
          .doOnNext(s -> log.info("received {}", s))
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic());
    }
}
```

basic logic is http put request to localhost:port/test will receive what it send to server as plain text

I try to make doOnNext run on other Thread rather than Spring WebFlux's NIO Thread, no matter where I put

```
subscribeOn
```

the execution Thread always be NIO Thread:

```
INFO 23200 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] c.a.p.m.f.service.router.TestService     : on subscribe
INFO 23200 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] c.a.p.m.f.service.router.TestService     : received test
```

---

Thanks to @MichaelBerry @SimonBaslé, Both of you helps me a lot, upvote both of your answers

In short reactor-netty will overriden subscribeOn for http subscription,  use a `flatMap()` to include a separate `subscribeOn()` on a different `Mono/Flux` or `publishOn()` can do the job I want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't something you can change - it's only the last `subscribeOn()` call in the chain before `subscribe()` is called that's honoured, so it's up to WebFlux to use whatever scheduler it wants to. In this case it looks like it's handling the requests in an NIO driven event loop or similar.

However, you can include a `flatMap()` call in your chain, for which you *can* specify a separate `subscribeOn()` which *won't* be overriden. This may be an option depending on your use case, as you could do the bulk of the work in a publisher defined in the `flatMap()` call.

Comment: Hi Michael, I searched entire spring-webflux&reactor-netty try to locate possible subscribeOn() but I can only find one place in `StandardWebSocketClient` which should be a `Client`  not a `Server` so it seems not be our case

Comment: And when I add BreakPoint into `subscribeOn()`,no other execution ran into this bp rather than my own sbscribeOn

Comment: @revivn I encourage you to read more about publishOn vs subscribeOn, see for instance the few slides on it at https://speakerdeck.com/simonbasle/flight-of-the-flux?slide=54

Comment: reactor-netty does something internally that is similar to `subscribeOn`, but isn't directly using the operator IIRC. it submits requests to netty and lets netty do the publication of its HTTP responses on netty's own threads, which effectively boils down to the same.

Comment: @SimonBaslé For clarity's sake, is that aimed at myself or revivn? Certainly happy to delete or amend this answer if I'm unintentionally putting incorrect information out there.

Comment: @MichaelBerry clarified, this was intended at @revivn ;) I think `publishOn` would help here, since she/he seems to want the `onNext` to happen on a particular thread. reactor-netty won't let you make the http request (aka subscription) in anothe thread, because of the way Netty itself works.